# Why isn't this javascript/form working

Tags: javascript, forms

The user is supposed to be able to enter an address in the form and the Javascript will open a new window with the directions. But when the button is pressed, nothing happens. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Javascript:

```
function ShowDirections() {
    var street = document.getElementById('street').value;
    var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
    var state = document.getElementById('state').value;
    var zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;
    var from = street + ', ' + city + ', ' + state + ' ' + zip;

    var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&amp;hl=en&amp;saddr=" + from + "&amp;daddr=1530+Commercial+Street%2c+East+Weymouth%2c+MA+02189";
    window.open(url, 820, 700);
}
```

HTML:

```
<label for="street">Address or Intersection:</label>
<input name="street" type="text" id="street" />
<label for="city">City:</label>
<input name="city" type="text" id="city" />
<label for="state">State/Province:</label>
<input name="state" type="text" maxlength="2" id="state" />
<label for="zip">Zip/Postal Code:</label>
<input name="zip" type="text" maxlength="10" id="zip" />
<input type="button" value="Get Directions" onclick="javascript:ShowDirections();" />
```

Comment: Use a `button` (with a `type` of `button`) instead, and attach a `click` hander to your `button` instead of a `javascript:` action. Also, check your JavaScript console for errors.

Comment: where is `popup` defined?

Answer (score 1):

`javascript:` isn't an acceptable action for `form` tags. It needs to be a URL. Take it all out of the form and place a handler on the submit button (as a button) and you might be closer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onsubmit` to call javascript function